# Representing a series in terms of another

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, formal-power-series

I would like to know wether it is possible to represent $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (1/4-k)}{n!} a_n x^n$$ in terms of $$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

I have tried to represent the product and the $n!$ as a binomial coefficient, but once there I do not know what to do and how to continue (both differentiation and integration seem useless). In other words, I do not know where to start from.

Any help/idea will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I think the OP defined how to get from $a_n$ to $b_n$, but he wants to know how to get from $g(x)$ to $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that the series $$g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n\,x^n$$ has convergence radius $R$. This means that it converges for some positive $x=r<R,$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\,r^n=0$ and thus $|an\,r^n\le C$ for some $C>0$ and $n\ge0.$ Then, the series is absolutely convergent for $|x|<r$: $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}|a_n\,x^n|\le\sum^\infty_{n=0}C\,r^{-n}\,|x^n|=\frac{C}{1-\frac{|x|}{r}}.\tag1$$
Let $$c_n=\frac{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n (k-1/4})}{n!}.$$ Obviously, $c_n=O(n^{-1/4})$, so the radius of convergence of both series is equal. The sequence $c_n$ can be represented by the beta function, $$B(x,y)=\int^1_0t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}:$$ From the well-known recursion $$B(x+1,y)=B(x,y)\cdot\frac{x}{x+y}$$ we get immediately $$c_n=\frac{B(n+3/4,1/4)}{B(3/4,1/4)},$$ where by Euler's reflection formula $$B(3/4,1/4)=\frac{\Gamma(3/4)\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(1)}=\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac\pi4}=\pi\sqrt{2}.$$ So $$f(x)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\left(\int^1_0t^{n-1/4}(1-t)^{-3/4}\,dt\right)\,a_nx^n.$$ The series on the RHS is absolutely convergent for $|x|<r$ because of (1), so we can interchange the order of summation and integration.
This means $$f(x)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{2}}\int^1_0t^{-1/4}(1-t)^{-3/4}g(-tx)\,dt,$$ and this derivation is valid in every closed subinterval of the interval of convergence, since the series is absolutely convergent, there.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Just a couple of questions. That $(-1)^n$ comes from the change of $(1/4-k)$ to $(k-1/4)$, isn't it? And would your last step be valid if either the series $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ were only conditionally convergent? Btw, the original sum of $f(x)$ started in $n=1$, but that's not a problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, the $(-1)^n$ comes from there. Even if the series is only conditionally convergent for some $x$, it is absolutely convergent for smaller absolute values of SxS, and the derivation is valid, there. If the formula is valid for an $x$ where the series is only conditionally convergent, is another question, that really depends on the concrete $a_n.$ If your sum starts only from $n=1,$ that's not a problem, you'll just have $g(0)=0$ and thus $f(0)=0.$

Comment: Sorry but, what do you mean with smaller values of $x$? For example, would $|x| \le 1$ satisfy that condition?

Comment: Smaller than the radius of convergence of the original series for $g(x).$

Comment: One more doubt (hopefully I am not late): why will the later integral converge on the same region than the original $f_2(x)$? What if $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left | \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (1/4-k)}{n!} a_n x^n \right | \to \infty$$ It would not be possible to interchange the integral by the sum

Comment: @user3141592 I explained that in comments, already, but I've edited it in some more detail into my answer, now.

Comment: But imagine that, like most of the OGF, $g(0)=1$. Then, wouldn't the integral diverge because of the $t^{-1/4}$ (sorry for my insistence, but I am having some trouble with the convergence of the integral)